# How to use correctly struct type in c?

Tags: c

I don't understand why my code never end ?

I think the problem comes from p.Nbrepoints, p.Longueur and my printf doesn't work.

When I compile this code I don't have any errors.

I'm a beginner in c. How to use correctly my struct Parametre ?

Normally : printf("%g",p.Nbrepoints) would gives 81 ? no ?

Do you have any ideas to do this properly ?

Thanks you

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

struct Parametre
{
    int Longueur;
    int Nbrepoints;
    int tend;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct Parametre p = {2,81,2};

    double dx=p.Longueur/(p.Nbrepoints-1);
    printf("dx=%g",dx);
    double dt=dx/2.;
    double*x=NULL,*U=NULL, *u=NULL; 
/**
 dynamic allocation 
*/
    x= calloc(p.Nbrepoints,sizeof(double));
    U= calloc(p.Nbrepoints,sizeof(double));
    u= calloc(p.Nbrepoints,sizeof(double));
  
/**
 Boundary condition
*/
    u[0] = 0.;
    u[p.Nbrepoints-1]=0.;
    
/**
initial elevation: a "bump", position 
*/
    double t=0.;
    for(int i=0; i<p.Nbrepoints;i++)
    {
        x[i+1] = x[i] + dx;
        u[i] = 1.;
    }
    for(int i =10; i<20;i++)
        u[i]=2.;

/**
 Boundary condition
*/
    u[0] = 1.;
    u[p.Nbrepoints-1]=1.;
/**
 begin the time loop
*/
    FILE *fic = fopen("data.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fic, "%s %s %s\n", "#x", "#u", "#t");
    
    while(t<=p.tend)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<p.Nbrepoints;i++)
            fprintf(fic, "%g %g %g\n", x[i], u[i], t);
        fflush(fic);
        memcpy(U,u,sizeof(double)*p.Nbrepoints);
        for(int i=1;i<p.Nbrepoints;i++)
            u[i] = U[i] - (U[i]*dt/dx)* (U[i] - U[i-1]);
        fprintf(fic,"\n\n");
        t+=dt;
    }
    free(U); 
    free(x);
    free(u);
    fclose(fic);
    return 0;
}
```

my data.txt file :

```
#x #u #t
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 2 0
0 2 0
0 2 0
0 2 0
0 2 0
0 2 0
0 2 0
0 2 0
0 2 0
0 2 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0


0 1 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
0 -nan 0
```

Comment: `t+=dt` what is the value of `dt` here? The obvious way to this to run forever is for `dt` to equal zero.

Comment: tl;dr of dupe: `double dx=p.Longueur/(p.Nbrepoints-1);` does integer division even though it puts the result in a `double`.

Comment: Please [edit] and show a minimal example of the `data.txt` file that triggers the problem.